# Firebase Realtime Database rules error in flutter. How to fetch them

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, error-handling

I am currently trying to make the user input a username to my flutter application. I currently have these rules on firebase which allows only unique usernames to be added.
My problem is I cannot fetch the error when I am trying to add the username to the database by calling the method below when pressing a button.
I am using Firebase Realtime database.
Here is the code where I add the username:

```
Future<User?> addUsernameToDatabase(String? username) async {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if(user != null)
    {
      //GuestUser
      if(user.isAnonymous)
      {
        print("Guest user");
        final uid = user.uid;
        user.updateDisplayName(username);
        await _dbRef.child('usernames').child(user.displayName!).set(uid);
      }else{
        final uid = user.uid;
        setLoading(true);
        try{
         user.updateDisplayName(username);
         await _dbRef.child('usernames').child(username!).set(uid);
         setLoading(false);
        } on PlatformException catch (error){
          print(error.toString());
          setLoading(false);
        } on DatabaseError catch (error){  
          print(error.toString());
          setLoading(false);
        } on Exception catch (error){
          print(error.toString());
          setLoading(false);
        }     
      }
    }
  }
```

Here are the rules on firebase. Btw they work if a user inputs a username and already exits it will not add it.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "users":{
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        ".read": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'password'",
        "username": {
          ".validate": "
            !root.child('usernames').child(newData.val()).exists() ||
            root.child('usernames').child(newData.val()).val() == $uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also the data in firebase realtime database looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gKuZ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rules define no access for `/usernames`, so trying to read or write `_dbRef.child('usernames')` from within your app will fail.

From reading your code, these are the rules you want to add:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "usernames": {
      "$username": {
        ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.val() === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```